# fabric.js - How can I push fabric image object into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```
    //STARS
    var stars_arr = new Array(6);
    for(a=0;a<6;a++){
        fabric.Image.fromURL(
            './img/util/star.png',
            function(output){
                canvas.add(output);
                stars_arr[a] = output;
            },
            {
                left:75+(a*29),
                top:30,
                width:23,
                height:25,
                selectable:false
            }
        ); 
    }
    console.log(stars_arr);
```

I want to push my each star image object into an array because I will modify some prosperities of them.
But the console told me 
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
and stars_arr.length = 0

Answer (score 2):

You've probably long figured this out - but in case someone else stumbles upon it:  The problem here is due to fabric.Image.fromURL being asynchronous. All iterations of your loop complete before ANY of your callback functions are executed. So when they finally are executed, your `a` variable is already 6, and remains 6 for all 6 iterations.

The easiest way to fix this is to encapsulate your call inside a function which is called from the loop. Such as:

```js
//STARS
var stars_arr = new Array(6);
for (a = 0; a < 6; a++)
  addStar(a);

function addStar(a) {
  fabric.Image.fromURL(
    './img/util/star.png',
    function(output) {
      canvas.add(output);
      stars_arr[a] = output;
    }, {
      left: 75 + (a * 29),
      top: 30,
      width: 23,
      height: 25,
      selectable: false
    });
}
```

In doing so, references to `a` within your callback refer to the `a` passed into the function, not the `a` loop variable - and so it retains its value from each call.